# content placeholders pages not showing inside master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'a currently working on C# aspx.net project, and all of a sudden the pages that should load inside master page are not shown, it's like "hidden", only master page is showing, i didn't do nothing revelant to it, i think.
It's getting me insane because i already loaded a backup that i got, and the same problem occurs. So maybe i did something wrong to my Visual Studio 2019? 
Does that ever happened to anyone?
I've tryed to change the Netframework from 4.5 to 4.6 but the problem persists.
if i inspect the page on google devtools, the page's are there, but not showing on the content placehonder.

Example of my master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Masterpage.Master.cs" Inherits="WORKFLOW_FACTURE.Site1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
....
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    </div>

<div id="page-wrapper">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

example of one page that should be loaded whenthe user enter the masterpage:

```
<%@ Page Title="" EnableEventValidation="false" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Masterpage.Master" CodeBehind="Indicateurs.aspx.cs" Inherits="WORKFLOW_FACTURE.Indicateurs" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<form runat="server">
....
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
...
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: if I had to guess I'd say maybe there's an error in your HTML somewhere. These things don't happen for no reason "all of a sudden" either. Try and think back to what you changed around the time it started happening. P.S. the .NET framework version and the Visual Studio version will be entirely irrelevant to this issue. It's somewhere in your code. But since you've shown only a very minimalist example it's hard to know what it might be.

Comment: Adyson, the thing is that i've loaded the backup project, that i didn't touch and know that was working and the same problem occurs.

Comment: have you examined the HTML output of the page to see if any of the content is there but somehow hidden? Have you debugged anything in the code-behind to see if there's something not running where you expected? If you claim you didn't change anything, it's quite hard to see how this could have occurred, unless what's being injected into those placeholders is perhaps dynamically generated by the code-behind? Errors don't just come from nowhere. **something** must have changed. But all we can do is make debugging suggestions. The code you've shown doesn't allow us to understand the issue directly

Comment: For some reason the classes col-md / col-lg etc aren't working properly.
if i delete that class on devtools, the div / button / object are shown..
what can it be?

Comment: I have no idea precisely why that would be, because you haven't given us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem which we could use to diagnose it. Those sounds like bootstrap classes. So...if you need help with it please a) state your version of bootstrap, b) show the relevant HTML which is causing the issue (rather than just the aspx placeholders, which seems to be a red herring), c) explain what you expected it to look like, and what it actually looks like (screenshots might be useful). Thanks.

Comment: P.S. the process of working up the minimal example may actually lead you to the solution yourself anyway, because you have to examine each bit of code and decide if it contributes to producing the issue. So it's a useful exercise in root-cause analysis. You probably need to dig a bit deeper with your devtools and see precisely what CSS rule those classes implement which might cause the issue.

Comment: I do know they are related to responsive design, so perhaps you're simply viewing your page at the wrong screen size or something. But like I said, it's pretty much impossible to be sure without seeing the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Im going to work on it, now that i found the source of the problem. 
Maybe some class must be missing from repository and cause it to break all the load from the other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I alredy had that same problem on my asp.net application, where bootstrap classes weren't recognized.
**It can happen for two main reasons:**

**1 -** *the links *.css / script *.js are being called from the master page at bad order*, and  because of that, dind't load properly.

**2 -** *Calling bootstrap.css instead of bootstrap.min.css*, that happened to me, i think that's because of the load time that can be relevant to the content page.

Comment: Problem solved!! 
Thank you Brunou!! That was the problem, called bootstrap.css instead of bootstram.min.css, and put it on the first place at the links .css section.